# https falsly redirects to another domain on same server

Tags: apache, redirect, mod-rewrite

I have a server (Ubuntu 14.04/LAMP) running several websites from different clients. I have an old site  (let's call it OLDSITE.COM) that the client wanted to shut down. In the apache site conf I did a rewrite:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [G,NC]
```

which correctly gives a 410 Gone. The problem is that if I call https://OLDSITE.COM it somehow redirect to a complete different domain (let's say RANDOMCLIENT.COM) which is also hosted on my Server.

I even tried to have another redirect like

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [G,NC]
```

which didn't change anything, and I also tried

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS_HOST} ^(www\.)?OLDSITE\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [G,NC]
```

I can't get https://OLDSITE.COM to give a 410 Gone.

But I think the general question is why does it redirect to the other domain? To test this random redirect I shortly disabled the site RANDOMCLIENT.COM to see what happens then, and what did happen was that by calling https://OLDSITE.COM it goes to ANOTHERRANDOMCLIENT.COM. So what is happening here? Why does Apache redirect to other domains on the Server? And why does he do it even when I have a redirect for OLDSITE.COM?

Same thing happens if I disable the conf for OLDSITE.COM and this is really strange for me, because if Apache gets a request for a ServerName that is not on the Server, shouldn't Apache automatically give something like "Not Found"?

I have absolutely no clue and I am completely desperate...
Thanks for any Idea

Comment: Nope, if the ServerName is not matched, the first VirtualHost will be used.

Comment: Ok, didn't know that, thanks. My problem with the https redirect was because I didn't have a ssl certificate for OLDSITE.COM and so the https request couldn't get through. Now with the certificate the redirect works perfectly.